# How to execute a chef recipe on a cloud cluster node?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

I have two nodes

chef server => nodeA and  nodeB

I have two recipes : a_recipe and b_recipe

I do bootstrap from chef server to nodeA and I execute this recipe 'a_recipe' .

My goal is :

```
- execute recipe  'b_recipe' on nodeB during execution of 'a_recipe' on nodeA
For example:
a_recipe code

#cookbook : TEST
#recipe   : a_recipe

-----some code--------
#call 'b_recipe' on nodeB
------some code...........
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-server orchestration is not something Chef supports directly. Chef itself is primarily a server-level (node-level) agent. You can look at tools like Chef Push Jobs, MCollective, SaltSack, and RunDeck for features like this.

Comment: Ansible handles this pretty cleanly.

Comment: Kind of, but it has the advantage of being an inherently multi-node tool even when N=1 for the normal case.